# Overlay view over video in iphone

Tags: iphone, view, overlay

I am working as iPhone developer. I want to add overly view over video in iPhone. Overly view will have buttons and labels on it. In short video be used as background instead of uiimage .Is it possible or not? If possible, then how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is what you want but if it is you can try this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.mySecondView belowSubview:self.myThirdView];
```

in that way, the "mySecondView" will appear over the "myThirdView"

Comment: This code i used:                                          [self.view insertSubview:moviePlayerController.view belowSubview: singleWidgetView];                                                     I am using "SingleWidgetView" as an overly view over video view. "SingleWidgetView" will have some buttons and labels that appear on top of video view. Video will be an a way abackground.